# why is inplace=True making a bug in sort_values of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, and I know using of inplace=True is deprecated, but I wanna know why my first code doesn't prompt any error:

```
google = pd.read_csv("google_stock_price.csv").squeeze()
google = google.sort_values()
google.sort_values(ascending = False, inplace = True)
```

but if I delete the second line, I will get an error with this code:

```
google = pd.read_csv("google_stock_price.csv").squeeze()
google.sort_values(ascending = False, inplace = True)
```

the error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMBKT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `sort_values` function must have an parameter passed to the `by` argument.

Please check this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and study the `by` argument. It must take either row or column names, which again changes by axis. There is no default value for `by` which means you have to pass a parameter if you do not want an error thrown. I am not aware of `inplace` being deprecated but some do discourage its use.

Comment: This is not answering the question at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `read_csv`, the returned object is a `DataFrame`. When you use `squeeze` on a `DataFrame`, there are 2 possibilities:

1. The dataframe has only one column and you get a view of this column as a `Series`.
2. The dataframe has more than one column and the dataframe is untouched.

So, `sort_values` on a view of an object with `inplace=True` raises this exception:

`ValueError: This Series is a view of some other array, to sort in-place you must create a copy`

That's why you first code works: the first `sort_values` returns a copy of this view. After that, you can use `inplace=True`, it's not a problem.

Comment: yes my csv file has only 1 column, so I didn't need to use "usecols", so you mean in order to use inplace = True in sort_values on series, I should always first make a copy of original data? Is there any alternative way?

Comment: No, it's not possible since `squeeze` parameter of `read_csv` has been deprecated :( And you know `inplace` is also deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you the problem. The in-place sort does not work on views of arrays. If you check the documentation of the `squeeze()` function, it probably returns a view of the imported csv. As the message states, `copy()` the squeezed array first.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort this series in-place, you should create a copy of origin series at first.

do like this:

```
google = google.copy()
google.sort_values(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'd encourage you to read existing answers before posting in the future, as this was already suggested in another answer.  There doesn't seem to be a good reason to add another answer here if it doesn't offer something new.  Thanks!